# Scaffold-DbContext to different output folder

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm implementing repository pattern in company solution I work for, separating model classes in a Backend project and database context and migrations in DbContexts project.

I'm using Scaffold-DbContext setting my Backend Project as default project to destination of model classes, however DbContext Class is always created in same folder as model classes. Is it possible to redirect the creation of the DbContext class to a different output folder, in my case to DbContexts project?

Comment: As additional comment, that does not really belong to the answer: unless you have a good reason to hide EF (such as thinking on removing it on the future), it is not a really good idea to put it behind another layer. Do keep in mind that EF is both a Repository (through `DbContext`) and a Unit of Work (through `DbSet`) implementer.

Comment: You can refer to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63254065/9518407) I've worked in this way.

Comment: use `-OutputDir "Models" -ContextDir "DbContexts"` to seperate folder creation for entities and dbcontexts.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is now possible to redirect the generated context with -ContextDir option:

> **-ContextDir**    The directory to put DbContext file in. Paths are relative to the project directory.

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "*connection*" "*provider*" -OutputDir "BackendProject" -ContextDir "DbContexts"
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: I know that in the documentation it says that -ContextDir path is relative to the project directory, but if you put an absolute path it also works. Like that, you can generation the context and the entities in 2 different projects (not only different folders in the same project)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do that with my "EF Core Power Tools" free Visual Studio extension:

https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF-Core-Power-Tools

Comment: That extension is so cool. I Already tried and you can generate your entities and context in different projects (i was looking for that too) you can select the namespace, the folder and if you want to generate the entities, the context or both. This is a good solution ^

Comment: Can EF Core Power Tools support other DBMS, or only MS SQL SERVER?

Comment: Azure SQL, Postgres, MySQL, SQLite

Answer (score 10):

I faced a similar problem. I had my EF models in a separate project. In order to write the models there, I just used the following command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=[Server];Database=[Database Name];Trsted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Project "[Project Name]" -Force
```

The key for me was the `-Project "[Project Name]" -Force` option.

As the top answer indicates, if you want a different folder within that project, you can just use the `-OutputDir` option.

Comment: you can also use `cd` to navigate to seperate project then scaffold-dbcontext

Answer (score 5):

You can generate models and DBContext in different projects (not only different folders in the same project) like this :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir "C:\MySolution\DataAccessLayer\Context" -OutputDir "C:\MySolution\DomainLayer\Models" -Namespace "DomainLayer.Models" -ContextNamespace "DataAccessLayer.Context"
```

1. Note that the specified paths are **absolute**.
2. I know that the documentation says that the path is relative to the project. But it does not forbid to put an absolute path.
3. The -Namespace and -ContextNamespace are optionnal but I use the to keep my namespaces in sync with class location.

Answer (score 3):

**Scaffold-DbContext to different output folder:**

---

- With help of *Package Manager Console*

- `Scaffold-DbContext 'ConnectionString' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir MyDbContextFolder -OutputDir EntitiesFolder`

---

- With help of *.Net CLI*

- `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold 'ConnectionString' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context-dir MyDbContextFolder --output-dir EntitiesFolder`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the **Default Project** to the project which you want to generate entities in, also specify the folder (using OutputDir switch) where you want to generate the model definition. Example is below

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=SSPI;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -**OutputDir** **Models** -f -d

Answer (score -2):

As indicated by ihebiheb
Here is an example

context-namespace, namespace for your class
context-dir, folder in which you will leave the context of your classes
namespace, space name for each class in the database
output-dir, output folder for each class in the database
f, to overwrite the data that exist in the output folder for each class in the database

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "connectionstring" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --context-namespace "apitienda.dal.Context" --context-dir "Context" --namespace "apitienda.dto.Entities" --output-dir "../apitienda.dto/Entities" -f

tienda
--apitienda.api
--apitienda.dto
--Entities
--apitienda.dal
--Context

Comment: Sorry, but your answers is very unclear, basically a blur of words. The answer you refer to is much clearer Also, this question has been answered sufficiently and doesn't need more answers.