# Putting scaffolded EF entities in different directory than context

Tags: ef-core-3.0

**Question:** Is there a way to get `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to not only put the context file in a different directory but include the entity namespace in that file?

I'm using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to generate an EF context and related entities from a database. The database design is handled separately, so regenerating the entities and context periodically will be required.

I'm using this, which works fine:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold `
    "Server=localhost;Database=My.Db;Trusted_Connection=True;" `
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer `
    --startup-project My.EfCliStartupProject\My.EfCliStartupProject.csproj `
    --force `
    --project My.Orm\My.Orm.csproj `
    --context MyContext `
    --schema MY_SCHEMA `
    --output-dir Entities
```

I'd like to be able to put the scaffolded context one level up by adding `--context-dir .`. Unfortunately, there's no `using` statement at the top of the context file referencing the entity namespace.

This command is in a quick PowerShell script to do this that also clears out the entity directory, so it wouldn't be impossible to to add some code to that script to append the `using` statement, but that's not ideal.

I'm using EF CLI 3.0.0. Trying to install later versions gets me an error: `error NU1202: Package dotnet-ef 3.1.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0`.

There is [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282223/scaffold-dbcontext-to-different-output-folder) for `Scaffold-DbContext` with a mix of answers, but it's not clear if the `using` statement is expected to be missing or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This feature was included in version 3.1 of the tool, which I suppose is why you were having this problem on 3.0.0.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/18405