# Approach for sharing Entity Framework generated Models with REST Client Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that returns info from a Database. I am using Entity Framework Core and abstracted the DB context and models to a "DataAccessLibrary" class library. I used the DB First approach, scaffolding the Database and this created the models for me.

I now want to write a REST client application that can make requests to the Web API. I want to use the same models that are used in the DataAccessLibrary class library to deserialise the response JSON data to. I want to avoid manually copying the models.

How can I share the models with the client application, without directly taking a dependency on the DataAccessLayer class library? (The only reason I do not want to do this is because I do not want the client to also have a dependency on Entity Framework and also do not want to share the DB_Context)

Here is my project structure if I was unclear:

[image]

I want to somehow use the DataAccessLibrary's models in the REST Client application, without having to copy them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285156/9383868) to another question that addressed my question. I am posting this here to help someone in the future.

Through the Visual Studio Extension [Entity Framework Core Power Tools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki), I was able to Reverse engineer my database and was able to specify a different project for the DB Context and DB Models.

Now my solution looks as follows:

[image]

The IsoDatabaseContextLibrary now references the IsoDatabaseModelLibrary project, which contains the database tables deserialised into models. I am now free to reference the IsoDatabaseModelLibrary in my REST client, without taking the dependency on EF Core, and use the same models as I am using in my actual API.

I must add that following this approach required me to fix the using statements in the ISO_DB_LocalContext file, as it still expected the Models to be in the same project.

If someone has a command that I can insert into the Package Manager Console that would do the same, It would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I want to assume your DataAccess is your DbContext. 
Services Oriented Architecture is fine to use. 
Create another folder called ViewModels, it’s like a replica of your Models but with important variables.
Then use the Services approach by creating two seperate folders:
1) Interfaces
2) Implementation of your interfaces

Dependency injection and interaction with DbContext is done in your implementation rather than your controller. Models are used in your implementation.

The controller should only contain your endpoints and use methods from your interface. ViewModels are used in your controller.

Comment: I want to reference the models of my DataAccessLibrary in a different application than the TemperatureAPI project. The other application (REST Client) should deserialise the JSON object to the same object that Entity Framework used to get it from the DB.

This way, when I update the API's models, the Client will also get the changes, without the manual copying process.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, you can create another project that will serve as a Logic project. In there, you will reference all your models. All your implementation for every application you will need will be in that Logic project folder. Then in all your applications, reference ../YourAppFoldername/Logic.csproj. That makes all your API applications have a single place where Logic takes place.

Comment: For example, if you have TemperatureApi and WeatherApi, in your Logic folder you would have subfolders named TemperatureLogic and WeatherLogic.