# Is it possible to make Entity Framework separate scaffolding mapping into multiple classes, instead of auto-generating all mapping into a single file?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am running the Scaffolding command for Entity Framework to automatically create classes based on my database `DatabaseName`:

```
Scaffold-DbContext 
    "Data Source=COMPUTER; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=USER; Password=PASSWORD; trustServerCertificate=true;" 
    MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force
```

However, I am noticing that Entity Framework puts ALL of the mapping in that single context file `DatabaseNameContext.cs`. For me this means 5000+ lines of code of mapping all in one file, and it's just not as readable and 'clean' (separated) as I would like.

What I would ideally want is to create a `Mapping` folder under my project and have a map file per table, like so:

`UserMapping.cs`, `Purchase.cs`, `Product.cs` etc where inside of each is the relevant mapping for that single table.

Is there a way to do this automatically using Entity Framework, or would I have to manually do this to achieve this result? Thank you.

Comment: do you see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522955/10193401 and use folder

Comment: That makes `DatabaseNameContext.cs` go into a separate folder. But the mapping inside of `DatabaseNameContext.cs` remains all together rather than separated per each table.

Comment: Do you really need all those tables in a *single* DbContext? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a connection or database model. You can have multiple contexts, each covering different use cases or mapping the same table to different types. The classes and tables you need for reporting are usually very different from the classes/tables used for data entry and usually *not* used together.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos , what I meant was that the answer on that other StackOverflow question is to specify `-ContextDir` and `-OutputDir`. However, when I tested doing that, it still generated a single `DatabaseNameContext.cs` file where all of the mapping was put into the single file, which I do not want. I was hoping for a solution that would create one mapping class per each table (so if I have 40 tables then I'd have 40 mapping class files). Maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: @m0a and why do you want to put 40 **entities** together? You won't use all of them at the same time in any scenario. There's a logical separation between them already. That should be reflected in your ORM. The emphasis **matters**. ORMs don't deal with tables. Their job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables. Those objects will have collection properties that map to relations, eg `Blog.Posts` and `Post.Tags`. It's highly unlikely you'll ever have to work with 40 entity types in the same scenario

Comment: What I mean is, you're trying to solve the wrong problem. On one hand, [you can eliminate most of the mapping code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) by telling `dotnet ef` to use conventions and data annotations. I bet the 40 tables don't have 100 fields each. This could easily reduce the 5000 mapping lines to 0. On the other hand, you can specify which tables to include in each DbContext.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos To clarify, you are meaning to run the `Scaffold-DbContext` command separately per each Entity/table I have in my database? I'm still learning EF and I thought that doing it that way could break things. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `-ContextDir` and `-OutputDir` separately should give you the desired result. They can be the same actual value if needs be. You can also use [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) if you prefer a GUI. This also provides some features that EF Core doesn't, like scaffolding of Stored Procedures.

Comment: Can you explain further how this works? When I tested adding `-ContextDir` and `-OutputDir` in my Scaffold command, it still made `DatabaseNameContext.cs` hold all of my table mappings in it. What I am seeking is something that would generate a separate mapping `.cs` file for each table; e.g. if I have 40 tables then it would generate 40 mapping .cs files

Comment: Actually, your answer makes sense to me now if it is assumed that I run `Scaffold-DbContext` command once per each table in my database. (I am working with a single database with 40 tables in it). Is it okay to run the `Scaffold-DbContext` command once per each table I have in my database, or would that somehow corrupt the project?

Comment: I'm not sure what running the command multiple times would do. My answer was based on my experience of using `Scaffold-DbContext` in the past. Providing those two options has always created a `DbContext.cs` file and separate `TableName.cs` files for each table that define the classes. If that's not how it's behaving for you, I'm not sure why that would be, perhaps we're using different versions of EF Core? Try the GUI tool I linked instead, that might be a more reliable route to what you want.