# Adopting Entity Framework Core with legacy database or databasees with no administrative privileges what is the right approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I and the team which I work are used to develop software applications based on legacy databases or databases we have no administrative rights on them, meaning we can't create or drop tables add rename o delete columns or make any changes on database schema.

Databases are maintained and designed by the administrator that is the only one in charge to make changes against them.

I found db first pattern approach very useful to manage any similar  scenario.

When the database administrator makes some changes to the database, the software developer team can run the model update, get the model in sync with the database, and if it's needed rely on edmx diagram to rename classes and properties with respect of the naming convention adopted for the domain model which can be slightly different from the one in use at database level.

Now we would plan to move to entity framework core and I’m wondering what is the right approach considering database administrator doesn’t have any developer skills.

I thought db fist approach is still the right approach.

But how?

Scaffolding the existing database to create the model? 
And then how to keep in sync the model with the changes the database administrator commits to the database?

If the database admin add a new fields to tables to fulfill some new requirements do I need to manually modify all the involved classes? 
Run Scaffolding again?
That mean lose any changes done on the class before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739950/how-to-update-the-model-when-using-database-first-approach

Comment: We have a similar requirement where DBA makes all changes. We use code first migrations to create the script the DBA runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scaffolding after each schema change.

The generated classes are partial, so make any changes in another partial class file, and it will not be overwritten