# How to update the model in Database First Approach ASP.NET "Core" when the DB changes (A new table is added)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET core 2.0 MVC template and have a couple of issues:

i)I generated the models by scaffolding using database first approach given in 
[MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db). But now I have added a new table (Employees) and wish to include that table as a model. But when I run this command :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Table Employees - Force
```

then it overwrites my previous dbcontext class(removes all previous models and adds only Employee in it).How can I add only model related to that new table only keeping the previous models as such.

ii)similarly I can't figure out the way how to update a existing model if the table corresponding to it is modified(added new columns using sql server).If I scaffold then it erases all the code written in that model class earlier.

I can't find out any proper documentation for database first approach apart from the MSDN one which doesn't deal with updating the models when underlying DB changes.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to update an existing scaffold from the Database. Entity Core has no "database first" approach that is supported. You're expected to use `Scaffold-DbContext` initially for existing Databases then use Code-First Migrations onwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the model when using database first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739950/how-to-update-the-model-when-using-database-first-approach)

Comment: Thanks @Valuator

Answer (score 0):

You must delete the first one model and create a new, re-scaldfold all that you need

delete Model.Context.tt, Model.tt, Model.edmx

delete Entities string from Web.config

Create the EDMX and Context files the same way you did for the first tim

as @Valuator that is for Code first method

Comment: EDMX isn't relevant to EF Core.