# Update Entity Framework Specific Model in .net core

Tags: entity-framework

I developed my application by database first. Then I included Entity Framework in my application and also generated my models by using scaffold command.
Now I want to update my specific table for existing models. So that, my other models would not be modified.
Please, tell me what command should I need to write for scaffold command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the model when using database first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739950/how-to-update-the-model-when-using-database-first-approach)

Comment: You can view this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315147/how-to-update-the-model-in-database-first-approach-asp-net-core-when-the-db-ch?noredirect=1&lq=1