# Has Microsoft dropped support for database-first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, razor-pages, ef-database-first

So I've been programming WebForms and MVC for many years and I'm trying to get up to speed on Razor Pages.

One snag I'm hitting is how to get started with database access (using Entity Framework). In the past, I just created an EDMX file that built classes from my database. And I'm really more comfortable using database-first.

1. Has anyone seen any official word on forward support for database-first?
2. If it's not supported, anyone know any good tutorials that are current on setting up a database using code-first?
3. And if it's not supported, anyone know any good tutorials on porting an existing database over to a code-first project?

Comment: The `.edmx` file is gone, yes - the way to go for us database-first lovers would be to create your database separately (with SQL scripts), and then do a scaffolding "code-first using existing database" to create all the code-first classes from the existing database.

Comment: @marc_s: I don't know what's involved in that but it sounds like I'd be stuck making all updates to the database via the code. It's seems unfortunate that Microsoft suddenly removed one of the options.

Comment: I would agree with you - but I guess the amount of work needed to keep the `.edmx` around (with the advent of .NET Core/EF Core) even surpassed what MS is willing to invest... but I, too, find it a hard pill to swallow :-(

Comment: You can re-scaffold your model classes from the database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739950/how-to-update-the-model-when-using-database-first-approach/38784385#38784385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-6-3-preview-with-net-core-support/), the EDMX approach relies on a build task that is not (currently) available in .NET Core. However, the article describes this as a "temporary" limitation, suggesting that EF 6 will retain database first when it is fully ported to .NET Core in the shape of EF 6.3.

[EF Core does not support the EDMX file format for models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx). In my opinion, the move to make EF 6 compatible with .NET Core makes it less likely that EF Core will ever support EDMX. But I haven't seen anything official either way.

Comment: Yeah, it really feels to me like ASP.NET is in this sort of limbo state where version 5 is where things will start to come together. Until then, everything is in a state of change.