# How to update models in VS 2019 from database in Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, api, sql-update, visual-studio-2019

By VS 2019, I created an API project (database first), everything it's working well, now I made some changes in the database like add new tables and some property and modify data type for others and so on.., the question is how to update models to match the database in SQL?

this is a screenshot for my project:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739950/how-to-update-the-model-when-using-database-first-approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to recreate your models via Scaffold-DbContext with "Force" param.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=yoursource;Initial Catalog=yourdb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model -Force
```

Comment: if you want to expand your dbContext class, instead of creating another DbContext class, use option -Context. Generated code will be placed on a separated partial class file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi I am Considering you are using EFCore, please confirm !! 
As per available information over internet 
EF core for DB first ( from db to EF ) approach to Modify new/existing entity
```

you need to follow steps as:

1. EF model require to run Scaffold with flag Force

---

> EF model require to run Scaffold with flag Force  this will remove all
>   your local changes in model 
>   (for me it was IdentityDBContext and override identityUser changes)

---

2. after run the all your model migration
3. running all migration will bring everything in sync bw EF and DB

---

> now you need to do the local changaes again over solution
>   ( for me update IdentityDBContext and override identityUser changes
>   back as it was before db changes )

---

4. also as per below answer please notice EDMX object is not available yet,
   anyone has any clue then please share here.