# EfCore 3.1 tries to add a column that already exists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a working .NET Core 2.2 project, which I just upgraded to .NET Core 3.1

There is something weird with EntityFrameworkCore going on and I don't know where to start

I have the following (simplified) model:

```
public class Asset()
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid MainImageId{ get; set; }
   public Image MainImage { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image()
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid AssetId { get; set; }
   public Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

So an Asset has 1 MainImage.

This is defined in my model like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().HasOne(x => x.Asset).WithMany(x => x.Images).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

This definitely worked, until I upgraded. Now every time a SELECT happens on the `Assets` table, it is trying to select the column `MainImageId1`, which doesn't exist.
If I try to `AddMigration` I see that EF Core will add a column called `MainImageId1` and put a foreign key in place to the `Images` table.

I have tried adding the right column name to this property, but this also did not work:

`modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>().Property(x => x.MainImageId).HasColumnName("MainImageId");`

Does anyone have any idea how I can debug this further? Is something wrong perhaps in my DbContext class?

Comment: You need to update the mapping file (the model) when you change versions of Core.  there are addresses in the Core object that change with versions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you have any documentation for this? I'm trying to find something related to this, including reading through all the breaking changes listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes, but no luck yet

Comment: You need to REFRESH the model.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739950/how-to-update-the-model-when-using-database-first-approach

Comment: I am not working with Database first, but with code first, so I cannot refresh the model like that. All code in my model is hand-written;

Comment: A database can be a file or a server.  The input data in a file is a database.  The model has to be learned by Entity to be used.  The model get compiled so may be the settings in the compiler are not recognizing the new model (or compiling the model).  Open the csproj with notepad and see where the mode is being referenced.

Comment: I have already checked if it is using the model correctly by doing some database changes. These result in a correct migration being created, so I know my model is getting compiled and used. Still, EFCore does not seem to be able to make sense of my relationship from Asset to Image, and from Image to Asset

Comment: Guid Id is in the two tables.  So do you need to indicate the column is a KEY?

Comment: They were indicated as [Key]. I had omitted this in my code sample. I have updated my question so it shows the correct tags being used

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#fkp

Comment: Found the answer with some experimenting. I posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer. I was missing a property, which seems to be required to make sure Entity Framework understands the relationship.

```
public class Asset()
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid MainImageId{ get; set; }
   public Image MainImage { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image()
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid AssetId { get; set; }
   public Asset Asset { get; set; }

   //THIS WAS ADDED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:
   public ICollection<Asset> MainAssets {get;set;}
}
```

I added the collection `MainAssets` to the Images class and then updated my model to include the following two mappings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Asset)
    .WithMany(x => x.Images)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AssetId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
    .HasOne(x => x.MainImage)
    .WithMany(x => x.MainAssets)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.MainImageId);
```

And now everything works fine again. It seems that by adding the collection of `MainAssets` was key to having Entity framework understand the relationship better.